# How to update submodules in GIT

Tags: git

Is the following code enough to update submodules:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I do a git pull of the Main Project.

Then I do

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

to update the submodules.

Is that code enough?

Answer (score 36):

You can simply use `git submodule foreach git pull` to keep them updated once downloaded.

To get them along with the main project you can either use the `--recursive` parameter to the `git clone` command or use the command `git submodule update --init` once you have cloned the repo that contains them.

**EDIT**

I'd rather give a look at the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to fully understand the differences between the above mentioned commands, but I'll have also a try explaining them below.

The `git submodule update` command does the following:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of the submodules.

That means that it doesn't update the submodules to the latest available version, instead it checkouts the actual commit with which the superproject expects to work.

On the other side, the command `git submodule foreach`:

> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.

Because of that and assuming that the OP knows what the `git pull` command does, it's easily deducible that the combination of them can actually update all the submodules to the latest available commit.

For further details, see the link above.

Comment: `git submodule foreach git pull` is very different from `git submodule update`.  It would be worth it to explain the differences.

Comment: Done, even if there is nothing clear enough but the official documentation in this case. ;-)

Comment: When I tired the variant `git submodule foreach git fetch`, changes were fetched, but when I ran git submodule foreach git pull` I got an error: `You are nou currently on a branch.` `Please specify which branch you want to merge with.`

Comment: Solved my problem: The submodule repository actually had a "detached HEAD", so I added the HEAD to a branch and then pulled that branch from the submodule's directory.